# How to do 2D ground with depth sense in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I know do a horizontal and vertical scroller game (like Mario), in this game type, the character is always in the same distance from user. The character only moves to left and right in horizontal scroller and to down and up in vertical scroller.

But there are games in 2D that the character can move freely in the scene, like for example graphic adventures.

So how can I do that ground in order to move the character freely on the ground with depth sense?

An example can see in this video: http://youtu.be/DbZZVbF8fZY?t=4m17s

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do that:

First imagine that you are looking at your scene from the top to the ground. Set your coordinate system like that. So all object on your scene will have X and Y coordinates. All your object movements and checking (when character bumps into a wall or something), calculations do in that 2D world.

Now, to draw your world, if you want simpler thing, without some isometric perspective 3D look you just to draw your background image first, and then  order all your objects far to near and draw them that way. Devide your Y coords to squeeze movement area a bit. Add some constant to Y to move that area down. If you characters can jump or fly (move trough Y axe) just move Y coord to for some amount.

But if you want it to be more 3D you'll have to make some kind of perspective transformation - multiply your X coordinate with Y and some constant (start with value 1 for constant and tune it up until optimal value). You can do similar thing with Y coord too, but don't think it's needed for adventure games like this.

This is probably hard to understand without the image, but it's actually very simple transformation.